# How to determine a type alias with Scala Reflection?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

With Scala Reflection in 2.10, how can one determine if a type is a type alias?

The following does not work:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> typeOf[String].typeSymbol.asType.isAliasType
res46: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6474 caused by the fact that `Type.typeSymbol` automatically dereferences aliases.

```
scala> showRaw(typeOf[String])
res0: String = TypeRef(SingleType(ThisType(scala), scala.Predef), newTypeName("String"), List())

scala> typeOf[String].typeSymbol
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = class String

scala> typeOf[String].typeSymbol.asType.isAliasType
res2: Boolean = false

scala> val TypeRef(_, sym, _) = typeOf[String]
sym: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = type String

scala> sym.asType.isAliasType
res3: Boolean = true
```

A workaround, as partially provided by the REPL printout, is to perform manual pattern matching and extract the underlying symbol. An alternative is to cast to `scala.reflect.internal.Types#Type` and use `typeSymbolDirect`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in addition of `scala.reflect.internal.Types#Type`, you need to avoid `getClassByName()`: following [scala-dev issues 248](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/248), and [PR 5482](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5482), Scala 2.12.1 will ensure that:

- [`companionClass` returns a class, not a type alias](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/bd1858896f6546d778aa93c39b491ed5e2d7e0b3),
- [type aliases are not followed in getClassByName and friends](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/4e3ffd4bf00ab71ef64c31a45d5c3e2838aa78ee).

> This makes `getClassByName` fail / `getClassIfDefined` return `NoSymbol` when querying an alias.
>
> The current behavior can confuse the classfile parser: when parsing a
>   class, a cross-check verifies that `pool.getClassSymbol(nameIdx)`
>   returns the symbol of the class currently being parsed.
>   If there's a
>   type alias that shadows the linked class, following the alias would
>   return an unrelated class.